# How to setup Bamboo to work with codeception?

Tags: ant, bamboo, codeception

I have been trying to get Bamboo working with codeception tests. I am using codeception to test my code in a symfony project.

After some research I found an article on **[how to setup Jenkins with codeception.](http://codeception.com/05-24-2013/jenkins-ci-practice.html)**

Once read I figured out that I should use Ant to run the codeception commands that run the tests.

The problem is I don't really know where to put everything. [This article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Ant) explains all the fields for a new Ant task but nothing seem to work.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, this is how I have gotten codeception working in bamboo.

In Admin > Server Capabilities.  Add a new executable for Codeception with the path /usr/local/bin/codecept.

In your job, create a new task of type Command.  Set the executable as Codeception.  The arguments should be run --xml (and any others you need).

Next, create another task with the type of JUnit Parser.  Set the custom results directory to tests/_log/*.xml.

This works perfectly for me.

Additional:  If you do not have admin rights to the server, set the command executable as PHP and add ./vendor/bin/codecept run --xml as the arguments.

Comment: I am trying to follow the above instruction but facing some difficulties. 1) The way to setup executables is changed and mentioned in https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-a-new-executable-capability-289277164.html   2) I am not sure about the path /usr/local/bin/codecept. I installed codeception on my root folder as described on http://codeception.com/quickstart   and so didnt find any folder named codecept under /usr/local/bin/.  3) The job creation is also not clear.  So can you please add some more description?

Comment: FYI, Installed codeception on my root folder which is /var/atlassian/www/.